# A fake phone tech changed my start up password.

Tags: passwords

I was duped into believing a phone caller was a computer tech. I allowed him remote access and when I refused to pay a fee at the end of all his changes he hung up. My start up now has an unknown password. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for SuperUser.com - Also, please try to provide as much detail as possible if looking for an answer. Are you are running Windows, which version? There is also much to be said about blindly trusting people who cold call you, but I have a feeling you have learned that lesson already. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: My advice is to report this to the police. Unauthorised access is a violation of most countries' computer law (e.g. Computer Misuse Act in the US, Computer Fraud & Abuse Act in the UK). Call your local police station and ask who you should talk to about cyber-crime (that's usually what govm't types call it), and explain the situation. Whilst they won't fix your computer, they can at least pull phone records to identify the perpetrators.

Answer (score 5):

You have fallen victim of scammers. Best thing to do is to format your PC and restore it from backup. Reseting the password is not enough as they might have installed several backdoors which could allow remote access.

If they have such access they could steal your credit card data the next time you make a purchase from your computer ( or any other payment data such as bank login).

Comment: Agreed. I've worked as a tech in a few stores and I have seen this happen a lot. Many times they do indeed install back doors and all kinds of trash on your computer. I would follow the advice of @Lucas Kauffman here. Back up your files and wipe your computer. Even your backed up files, install a decent antivirus before restoring them and scan them all.